# MongoDB (C# Driver) issue deserialising an ObjectID field

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB to deserialise a document into a C# object and am having issues with ObjectID fields. This is the error I am getting:

> Required element 'LayoutId' for property 'LayoutId' of class MyProject.Data.MyDocument is missing.

Which (if it doesn't look odd anyways) does make sense because the LayoutId field IS specified:

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace MyProject.Data
{
  public class MyDocument
  {

    public override ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public ObjectId LayoutId { get; set; }

  }
}
```

And its populated in the database:

[image]

So what other aspects of the serialisation process could prevent this element from being populated? Is there a bug in a particular version of the driver? Am I using the right data type?

It should also be noted that:

- this document was used to populate that value in the database, so it appears that only deserialisation is an issue and serialisation is fine.
- there are other documents in the same library which have the same issue.
- there are mongo documents/contracts in the same solution but in a different library which do NOT seem to have the same prolem,

Comment: If you remove the BsonRequired attributes from your LayoutId properly, does the issue go away?

Comment: @CraigWilson If I do that then the field remains null. So somewhere in the deserialisation process the BSON field is not being matched to the class Field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Craig for attempting to solve this problem. It turns out that I had not written the question properly.

The problem was that I was calling "SetFields()" on the result, and the fields I was requesting did not include "LayoutId". I would have expected a more descriptive error from the driver though.

Comment: Not sure what type of better error message you would want.  It mentioned specifically that LayoutId was missing.  Do you have a suggestion for a better error message?

Comment: @CraigWilson Well the driver knows what class you are deserializing into and it knows what fields you are requesting. So something along the lines of "required field missing from specified in field list" might be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this error.  Can you update your question with test program?

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsole_Source
{
    class Program
    {
        public class MyDocument
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

            [BsonRequired]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [BsonRequired]
            public ObjectId LayoutId { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = MongoServer.Create();
            server.Connect();

            var db = server.GetDatabase("docstest");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<MyDocument>("docs");
            collection.Drop();

            var doc = new MyDocument
            {
                Name = "Test",
                LayoutId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId()
            };

            collection.Save(doc);

            var foundDoc = collection.FindOne();
            //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example code loads the document perfectly fine. I might add that there are other documents containing object-id's which work fine, so there is likely something non-mongo-related which is causing the document to fail deserialization.